# Accessing date directly in workflow.xml in case of oozie workflow jobs

Tags: hadoop, oozie

Input data path contains current date( INPUT/YYYY/MM/DD/HH/ ) and the oozie job is simply workflow job.

I tried the following, but didn't work.

```
<java>
    <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
    <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
    <prepare>
        <delete path="${nameNode}/user/510600/output" />
    </prepare>
    <main-class>${parse_mainClass}</main-class>
    <arg>${inputDir}/${YEAR}/${MONTH}/${DAY}</arg>
    <arg>${parse_Output}</arg>
</java>
```

By including the follwing in coordinator.xml. I can use the variable "prevDaystart" in workflow.xml.

```
<workflow>
    <app-path>${workflowAppUri}</app-path>
    <configuration>
    <property>
       <name>prevDaystart</name>
       <value>${coord:formatTime(coord:dateOffset(coord:nominalTime(), -1, 'DAY'),'yyyy-MM-dd')}</value>
    </property>
 </configuration>
```

My question is "Is there any direct way available to access the current date(YYYY/MM/DD/HH/) in workflow.xml (workflow jobs)? "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, no there is no way to access these variables in the workflow itself. I've always worked around this by adding in some additional dummy data outputs and properties that mirror the coordinator variables for year / month / day and then you can reference them in the workflow.